# Simple PHP image upload with error handling

Tags: php

I wrote this method to upload a floor plan image:

```
function upload_image($path, $file) {
    $errors = [];
    $ext = pathinfo($file["name"])['extension'];

    //randomly generate filename to avoid conflicts
    $filename = uniqid().'.'.$ext;

    if ($file["size"] > 2000000) {
        $errors[] = "The image cannot be greater than 2MB";
    }

    if (!in_array($ext, ["jpg", "jpeg", "png"])) {
        $errors[] = "The image can only be of .jpg, .jpeg or .png format";
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $path.$filename);
    }

    return array(
        "name" => $filename,
        "errors" => $errors
    );
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
if (isset($_POST['create'])) {
    $image = upload_image(IMG_PATH."/floorplans/", $_FILES['floorplan']);
    $floorplan = new FloorPlan($_POST['floorplan']);

    if (empty($image['errors'])) {
        $floorplan->image = $image['name'];
    } else {
        foreach ($image['errors'] as $error) {
            $floorplan->errors[] = $error;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm very happy with it and everything seems to work fine, but I am just wondering if there is a better/more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

- Rather than generate the full array of elements that `pathinfo()` generously offers only to access one value, use the `PATHINFO_EXTENSION` flag/option (the second parameter) to only ask for what you need.
- For best efficiency, don't perform any  unnecessary processes for disqualified incoming data.
- If you are going to declare `errors` at the start as an empty array, you won't need to call `empty()` which checks if the variable does not exist or if it is empty/falsey/null/zero-ish.  You can more simply use `!$errors`.  Alternatively, don't declare the empty errors array and then use `empty` to perform the double check.
- I assume that there is no point to generating a filename for an invalid submission, so I don't think that I'll support passing it with errors.
- I try to avoid declaring single-use and temporary variable where possible.  In this case, I'd avoid temporary variable by always dealing with the array to be returned at the end.

How my recommendations boil down...

```
function upload_image($path, $file) {
    if ($file["size"] > 2000000) {
        $outcome['errors'][] = "The image cannot be greater than 2MB";
    }

    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // force lowercase for uniformity

    if (!in_array($ext, ["jpg", "jpeg", "png"])) {
        $outcome['errors'][] = "The image can only be in .jpg, .jpeg or .png format.";
    }

    if (empty($outcome['errors'])) {
         // for the record, randomness does not guarantee uniqueness
        $outcome['name'] = uniqid() . '.' . $ext;
        move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $path . $outcome['name']);
    }

    return $outcome;
}
```

If you like rabbit holes, here's a good read regarding the security aspects of your task: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6484307/2943403

Answer (score 1):

There's not a lot of code here, but here's something I noticed.

```
foreach ($image['errors'] as $error) {
    $floorplan->errors[] = $error;
}
```

Since `$floorplan->errors` is expecting and array of errors, and `$image['errors']` is already an array of errors, why iterate through them and assign them to `$floorplan->errors` one by one when you can just assign `$image['errors']` to `$floorplan->errors`?

```
} else {
    $floorplan->errors = $image['errors'];
}
```